# What is the difference of converting to gray using different approaches or libraries?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image, color-conversion

The context here is that I am writing a code that combines multiple image pre-processing techniques, including converting images into grayscale (luminescence) images, to be applied on some arbitrary video file.

Currently feeding grayscale images to my code right now, but stumbled across an interesting observation when converting an image (that I'm pretty sure is grayscale, unless my eyes deceive me) to a grayscale image once again. Check the link below.

[On the left is the original screenshot. On the right is the image converted using skimage.color.rgb2gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o8qg.png)
**NOTE**: the two images shown in link are not 100% identical; I just put the two images next to each other before uploading them to here, but their appearance is the main take-away.

I'm curious if anyone here could share any insights into what is going on when I feed the original image into skimage's color conversion method. Pasted a snippet of my code below for y'all's own perusal. Not the best Python programmer and have been learning a lot while coding, so please let me know if there's anything egregious with what I did here.

Would greatly appreciate all help and insights! Thanks in advance.

```
        while capture.isOpened():
            read_success, frame_uint8 = capture.read()

            if not read_success:
                print("Converted all native frames into grayscale.")
                break

            frame_filepath = os.path.join(frameFolder, 'Frame{}.tiff'.format(frameID))
            cv.imwrite(frame_filepath, frame_uint8)

            frame_float = frame_uint8.astype(np.float64) / 255.0
            gray_result_float = skimage.color.rgb2gray(frame_float)
            gray_result_uint8 = (gray_result_float * 255.0).astype(np.uint8)

            gray_filepath = os.path.join(GRAYFolder, 'Frame{}.tiff'.format(frameID))
            cv.imwrite(gray_filepath, gray_result_uint8)

        capture.release()
```

Looked at skimage's documentation and saw that their RGB-grayscale conversion equation is as follows: Y = 0.2125 R + 0.7154 G + 0.0721 B. I understand people assign different weights to this general equation and that the differences aren't that noticeable, but could these seemingly arbitrary weights be contributing to the difference between these two images?

Booted up Adobe Photoshop and used its color dropper tool to pick up the HSB values of both images for a sanity check. The original image on the left has [0, 0, x] generally across all its pixels (where 20 < x < 50), but the converted image on the right has [120, y, z] (where y < 10 and 20 < z 50)

Comment: Well, if both `gray_result_float` and `gray_result_uint8` are single channel, as you would expect them to be, then problem is somewhere further down. How did you generate the image you attached to the question? | Why not use OpenCV for the colour conversion? You already use it to read the input and write the output. And you could avoid the unnecessary conversion to and from floating point... | Notice that the weights add up to 1.0. When the input is grayscale represented as BGR (i.e. `B=R=G`) as your input seems to be that's equivalent to selecting any single of the input channels.

Comment: Your question is a bit of a misnomer. IMO, it should be "what is the difference of converting to gray using different approaches or libraries". The answer to "what happens when I convert a gray image to a gray image using the same approach" is gonna be _libraries don't implement converting gray to gray, and if you manually implement it, it should technically remain the same-ish image_

Comment: I don’t understand what the problem is. Could you describe what you see in the images? If `capture` is from OpenCV, then the RGB color image is in reverse order from what skimage expects. OpenCV puts RGB images in reverse order, BGR.

Comment: if `R=G=B=Y` (gray-gray to color-gray) and `Y' = 0.2125 R + 0.7154 G + 0.0721 B` (color to gray), then `Y' = ( 0.2125 + 0.7154 + 0.0721 ) Y = 1.0 Y ` so Y' = Y

Comment: @TinoD Thank you for the proposed edit. Greatly appreciate it! Haven't used Stack Overflow to ask questions before and apologize for asking the wrong question. Will need to take some time to digest what everyone else here is saying in the meantime. Thanks again!

Comment: @DanMašek Thank you for responding and for the suggestions! I personally opted to use skimage as much as I could to streamline the number of computer vision methods I'm using in my code (i.e. didn't want to have OpenCV do what skimage could already be doing, if not better - to be confirmed, but just as an example). Now that I think about it though, that reasoning doesn't really make sense since I'm already using OpenCV to access the images. I didn't think about the chance of my input image being BGR yet - thank you for bringing that up! I'll change my code to remove the redundant conversion.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, "capture" is using OpenCV. From what I gather from other people's comments including yours is that I didn't realize from the beginning that OpenCV puts images in reverse order. I remember coming across that fact before a couple weeks ago but honestly forgot about it and didn't make the connection until now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: what? images aren't put in reverse order. it's merely the pixel format, putting channels in an order that used to be common, but is now less so because the name is hard to understand.

Comment: My apologies; I meant OpenCV changing the color channel order in the images from RGB to BGR when I said "reverse order".